# Errno 22 Invalid argument: In Snowsql

Tags: snowsql

I'm trying to execute a sql script using snowsql in below ways:

option1: !source C:\Users\"Local PC"\Documents\snowsql\test.sql;
or
!source C:\Users\Local%20PC\Documents\snowsql\test.sql;
I'm getting the below error. File is available in the location specified. Am I missing anything here?
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: C:\Users\Local%20PC\Documents\snowsql\test.sql.

Please let me know if I'm wrong anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue: I copied the file into the Current working directory on my windows machine(In my case, it was just \Users\Local%20PC) and then ran the command as below

!source test.sql